# Creating colorbar and setting edgecolor of Polygon Patch Collection Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have many polygon coordinates and each polygon region is associated with a score value. I am trying to visualize these polygons and their associated scores via a heatmap-like 2D plot. My code is able to plot something like this, however, I have trouble figuring how to display a colormap based on the color that I have set for the PatchCollection. Also, I have specified an edgecolor for the Polygon object but it is not showing up. The data that I'm using for plotting is attached [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vnofaop7hp3nf3o/polygons.pkl?dl=0).

```
import shapely
import pickle as pkl 
tiles = pkl.load(open("polygons.pkl",'r'))
area_lst=[]
for tile in tiles:
    area_lst.append(shapely.geometry.Polygon(tile).area)
sorted_ascend_tile_by_size= list(np.array(tiles)[np.argsort(area_lst)[::-1]])
gammas=np.random.random(len(tiles))
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)
patches = []
cmap = plt.get_cmap('cool')
colors = cmap(gammas)

for tile_idx in range(len(tiles)):
    polygon = Polygon(sorted_ascend_tile_by_size[tile_idx],closed=True,alpha=0.8,linewidth=1,edgecolor='black',fill=False,zorder=1)
    patches.append(polygon)

collection = PatchCollection(patches)
pcollection = ax.add_collection(collection)
collection.set_color(colors)

ax.autoscale_view()
```

This is the plot that code outputs:

[image]

I've tried adding a colorbar by using a ScalarMappable object, but I get the error `TypeError: You must first set_array for mappable`:

```
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=plt.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=1))
plt.colorbar(sm)
```

Answer (score 0):

As funny as it sounds but the error message actually already tells you the solution. Simply set an array to the `ScalarMappable` by using its `set_array` method. The array can be empty.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap="jet", norm=plt.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=1))
sm.set_array([])
plt.colorbar(sm)
plt.show()
```